# MySQL SQL Error [1411] [HY000]: Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'am trying to import data from csv i have a date data type which in the csv file is saved as %d-%b-%y (ex. 12-Aug-20)

The table

```
create table shows(
ShowID int unique,
Title varchar(255),
TypeID int,
Director varchar(255),
Cast blob,
DateAdded date,
year year,
Violence varchar(255),
Duration varchar(255),
Description blob

);
```

I tried running this script to populate:

```
INTO TABLE shows
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@ShowID,@type1,shows.Title,shows.Director,shows.`Cast`,@country,@date_added,shows.`year`,shows.Violence,shows.Duration,@c,shows.Description)
SET shows.ShowID =@ShowID ,
shows.TypeID = (select TypeID from typecountry t where t.`Type`=@type1 and t.Country=@country),
shows.DateAdded= STR_TO_DATE(@date_added , '%e-%b-%y');
```

and this error shows up :

> SQL Error [1411] [HY000]: Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

Comment: Can you provide the steps you followed to troubleshoot this error and where you need additional assistance? It's easier to guide you to an answer knowing the path you left off at

Answer (score 0):

You have value that are empty i your table, sp you need to repalce them

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE shows
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@ShowID,@type1,shows.Title,shows.Director,shows.`Cast`,@country,@date_added,shows.`year`,shows.Violence,shows.Duration,@c,shows.Description)
SET shows.ShowID =@ShowID ,
shows.TypeID = (select TypeID from typecountry t where t.`Type`=@type1 and t.Country=@country),
shows.DateAdded= STR_TO_DATE(IF (@date_added = '','01-01-1999', @date_added) , '%e-%b-%y');
```